# Is this Pfizer’s official Facebook page?

Tags: pharmaceutical, facebook

This [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Pzifer) purports to be that of [Pfizer](https://www.pfizer.com/), but it contains some unusual posts.

However, there is another [Pfizer Pharmaceutical page](https://www.facebook.com/Pfizer/) with a lot more Facebook Likes, so I’m not sure if this is legit or not. The rest of the page seems to be normal.

Is this Pfizer's official Facebook page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: The fake page is no longer available.

---

It is clearly **not** Pfizer's Facebook page.

- The URL is misspelt:

  - Correct: https://www.facebook.com/Pfizer/
  - Incorrect: https://www.facebook.com/Pzifer/
- The official page has a Blue Tick indicating it is verified. The fake page does not.

> [image: Comparison of pages]

- The official page has the [latest logo](https://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/pfizer_moves_pforward.php). The fake page has a logo that was replaced in 2009 (and oddly angled).
- The name of the company is wrong:

  - Correct Names include:

    - [Pfizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfizer)
    - Pfizer Inc.
    - [Pfizer Pharmaceuticals Inc.](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/78003/000095012303003360/y83976exv21.htm)
  - Incorrect: Pfizer Pharmaceutical
- The fake page [explicitly tells](https://www.facebook.com/Pzifer/posts/1558772587541559) people with problems to go to the official page:

> [image: Post telling users where the real page is]

Comment: Haha that’s sneaky. Thanks. If you’re still looking I’ll wait for the [more coming] because I think this is good information. I knew it was suspicious, but I didn’t know how to check.

Comment: Assuming you’re right (which certainly seems to be the case) this is “impersonation” and it’s against the rules. Someone with a Facebook account should report it (see https://m.facebook.com/communitystandards/spam/).

Comment: @Laurel I reported them. I’m not a fan of Big Pharma, but that doesn’t mean people should resort to lies. I wasn’t sure if this was a “practice Facebook” for their PR people, but the fake URL clearly shows it’s not. Those pictures are weird though.

Comment: I also found out that the snake picture is a photograph for [this Fortune magazine article](http://fortune.com/2011/07/28/inside-pfizers-palace-coup/), and it’s doubtful that Pfizer would want anyone to read it.